# How to use Navigator.pop() when redirectcheckout sends successurl or cancelUrl in stripe to flutter web view

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-web

I am trying to send the page back to my button screen after receiving success url or cancel url being received from stripe payment after the completion of the transaction in flutter web view

Can someone please tell me how do I achieve this, on receiving success url I want to use navigator.pop() and on receiving cancel url I want to use snackbar

Please find below code :

payment.dart

```
const TextButton(
                                      // textColor: Colors.white,
                                      child: Text(
                                        'PURCHASE',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            color: Colors.black87,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () => redirecToCheckout(plan[i]),
                                    ),

void redirectToCheckout(BuildContext _, var plan) async {
  final stripe = Stripe(apiKey);
  stripe.redirectToCheckout(CheckoutOptions(
    lineItems: [
      LineItem(price: plan, quantity: 1),
    ],
    clientReferenceId: '1',
    mode: 'payment',
    successUrl: 'https://localhost:8080/#/success/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancelUrl: 'https://localhost:8080/#/cancel',
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 different dart files success.dart and failure.dart.. add these classes on route too. Now on initstate of success you have to use `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil` and move it to the necessary page. On failure.dart again on initState move to the required pageand display a snackbar. Thats the only way for now to handle payment for flutter web using stripe